# Someone votes your question down without understanding it. Question gets ignored because it has negative votes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, unanswered-questions

Is there a solution if this happens to your question, esp. if the topic of the question is not that popular.

Comment: How do you *know* that they didn't understand it? If they genuinely didn't then you can assume that they felt the question wasn't clear enough - so you should see if there's anything you can do to edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: A question not being understood is a *fantastic* reason for downvoting it.  Unclear questions should be downvoted.

Comment: because I understood it... clearly I was not clear enough in the question.. suggest some edits, why downvote?

Comment: well getting downvotes on this one is poetic...

Comment: Of course you understood it; *you asked it*. You intrinsically have a much better idea of what you're asking, what your situation is and what you want.

Comment: @Optimus When someone doesn't understand what's being asked they *can't* edit it to make it understandable.  They'd need to understand it first.

Comment: @Optimus But it's not being ignored because of those downvotes, so it's not ironic.  I am disappoint in the lack of irony.

Comment: @Servy obviously I try to make my question more clear... but it is difficult to do that without constructive criticism, a downvote just tells you that your question was not liked, not the reason for it not being liked...

Comment: But a downvote **does** tell you useful information. Take a look at the hover tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is **unclear** or not useful" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Optimus yes, it would certainly be nice if someone could give you even more feedback then they already have.  There is always some way to give more feedback; that doesn't make the feedback that they did give in any way inappropriate or wrong.  It's also not just for you.  It's there to send a signal to all other readers that the question has problems.  That is useful information for those other readers.

Comment: @JonK yah.. i guess i'll just have to suck it up, my rant was that people are just way too quick to judge

Comment: Downvotes suck. They really do. I *know* that they're nothing personal, but I still take them personally despite knowing that. The trick is to take a step back and try and put yourself in the shoes of someone trying to answer your question, but being restricted to *only the information that's provided in your question*. I find it often helps to see what could do with some improvements in the question.

Comment: @JonK yah, they feel really bad... esp. if you think you have a very intelligent problem at hand... thanks for the discussion, I'll try to see what I can do to make my question clearer...

Comment: The part about getting ignored is intentional. When someone downvotes a question, they are basically telling other people, "this question is bad, don't waste your time here". It's all part of the quality control system. Stack Overflow gets 7000+ questions a day, and there are not enough people to review/answer all of them. So voting is used to separate the trash from the jewels. Good questions get attention and answers. Bad questions get ignored and deleted. It's actually very simple. If you want your question to get attention, it needs to be exemplary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your question more easy to understand.

The edit to your question will bump it, and it will get traffic again.  That traffic might lead to new upvotes.

Comment: I try to make my question more clear... but it is difficult to do that without constructive criticism, a downvote just tells you that your question was not liked, not the reason for it not being liked.